# Binding Issues with KnockoutJs and Breeze - Navigation Properties

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, breeze

My app is based on the HotTowel template so it includes Durandal, Knockout & Breeze.  I have a page with 3 tables side by side.  The first table has a list of "templates', the 2nd table shows "sections" for the selected "template" and the 3rd table shows "items" for the selected "section".  The "sections" and "items" tables are collections accessed via navigation properties.  I find that I get intermittent binding issues.  The data in the "templates" table always shows correctly, however related "sections" and "items" sometimes show correctly and other times one of the other is not populated.  It would seem to be a timing issue.  My view model and view are below.  Am I just going about all of this the wrong way?

```
define(['services/dataservice', 'services/logger', 'services/model'],
    function (ds, logger, model) {
        var templates = ko.observableArray();
        var selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
        var selectedSection = ko.observable();
        var selectedItem = ko.observable();
        var newTemplateTitle = ko.observable();
        var newSectionTitle = ko.observable();
        var newItemTitle = ko.observable();

        function activate() {
            newTemplateTitle('');
            newSectionTitle('');
            newItemTitle('');
            logger.log('Templates view activated', null, 'templates', false);
            return ds.getTemplatePartials(templates, false, false);//.then(succeeded);

            //function succeeded() {
            //    var firstTemplate = templates()[0];
            //    setSelectedTemplate(firstTemplate);
            //}
        }

        templates.subscribe(function() {
            var firstTemplate = templates()[0];
            setSelectedTemplate(firstTemplate);
        });

        var deactivate = function () {
            templates([]);
        };

        function refresh() {
            return ds.getTemplatePartials(templates, true, false);
        }

        var viewAttached = function (view) {
            bindEventToList(view, '#template-list', setSelectedTemplate);
            bindEventToList(view, '#section-list', setSelectedSection);
            bindEventToList(view, '#item-list', setSelectedItem);
            return true;
        };

        var addTemplate = function () {
            var newTemplate = ds.createEntity(model.entityNames.document);
            newTemplate.title(newTemplateTitle());
            newTemplate.isTemplate(true);
            newTemplate.organisation(ds.getCurrentOrganisation()());
            return ds.saveChanges().then(saveSucceeded);

            function saveSucceeded() {
                templates.push(newTemplate);
                templates.sort();
                newTemplateTitle('');
            }
        };

        var addSection = function () {
            var newSection = ds.createEntity(model.entityNames.section);
            newSection.title(newSectionTitle());
            newSection.isTemplate(true);
            newSection.document(selectedTemplate());
            return ds.saveChanges().then(saveSucceeded);

            function saveSucceeded() {
                newSectionTitle('');
            }
        };

        var addItem = function () {
            var newItem = ds.createEntity(model.entityNames.item);
            newItem.title(newItemTitle());
            newItem.isTemplate(true);
            newItem.section(selectedSection());
            return ds.saveChanges().then(saveSucceeded);

            function saveSucceeded() {
                newItemTitle('');
            }
        };

        var isTemplateSelected = function (template) {
            if (template && selectedTemplate()) {
                var thisId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(selectedTemplate().id);
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(template.id) == thisId;
            }

            return false;
        };

        var isSectionSelected = function (section) {
            if (section && selectedSection()) {
                var thisId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(selectedSection().id);
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(section.id) == thisId;
            }

            return false;
        };

        var isItemSelected = function(item) {
            if (item && selectedItem()) {
                var thisId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(selectedItem().id);
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id) == thisId;
            }

            return false;
        };

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            templates: templates,
            //sections: sections,
            //items: items,
            selectedTemplate: selectedTemplate,
            selectedSection: selectedSection,
            selectedItem: selectedItem,
            title: 'Template Maintenance',
            refresh: refresh,
            viewAttached: viewAttached,
            addTemplate: addTemplate,
            addSection: addSection,
            addItem: addItem,
            newTemplateTitle: newTemplateTitle,
            newSectionTitle: newSectionTitle,
            newItemTitle: newItemTitle,
            isTemplateSelected: isTemplateSelected,
            isSectionSelected: isSectionSelected,
            isItemSelected: isItemSelected
        };

        return vm;

        //#region internal methods
        function setSelectedTemplate(data) {
            if (data) {
                selectedTemplate(data);
                return selectedTemplate().entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("sections").then(setFirstSectionSelected);
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            function setFirstSectionSelected() {
                setSelectedSection(selectedTemplate().sections()[0]);
            }
        }

        function setSelectedSection(data) {
            if (data) {
                selectedSection(data);
                return selectedSection().entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("items").then(setFirstItemSelected);
            } else {
                selectedSection();
                selectedItem();
                return false;
            }

            function setFirstItemSelected() {
                setSelectedItem(selectedSection().items()[0]);
            }
        }

        function setSelectedItem(data) {
            if (data) {
                selectedItem(data);
            } else {
                selectedItem();
            }
        }

        function bindEventToList(rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
            var eName = eventName || 'click';
            $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () {
                var item = ko.dataFor(this); 
                callback(item);
                return false;
            });
        }
        //#region
    }
);

<section>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <header class="span12">
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right push-down10" data-bind="click: refresh">
            <i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
        <h4 class="page-header" data-bind="text: title"></h4>
    </header>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <section class="span3">
        <header class="input-append">
            <input id="newTemplateName"
                   type="text"
                   data-bind="realTimeValue: newTemplateTitle" 
                   placeholder="New template name"
                   class="input-medium" />
            <button class="btn btn-info add-on" data-bind="click: addTemplate, disable: newTemplateTitle() === ''">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>
        </header>

        <article>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Templates</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: templates -->
                    <tr id="template-list" data-bind="css: { 'selected': $root.isTemplateSelected($data) }">
                        <td data-bind="text: title" />
                    </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span>Count: <span data-bind="text: templates().length"></span></span>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section class="span5">
        <header class="input-append">
            <input id="newSectionName"
                   type="text"
                   data-bind="realTimeValue: newSectionTitle" 
                   placeholder="New section name"
                   class="input-medium" />
            <button class="btn btn-info add-on" data-bind="click: addSection, disable: newSectionTitle() === ''">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>
        </header>

        <article data-bind="if: selectedTemplate">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-bind="text: 'Sections for ' + selectedTemplate().title()"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: selectedTemplate().sections() -->
                    <tr id="section-list" data-bind="css: { 'selected': $root.isSectionSelected($data) }">
                        <td data-bind="text: title" />
                    </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span>Count: <span data-bind="text: selectedTemplate().sections().length"></span></span>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section class="span4">
        <header class="input-append">
            <input id="newItemName"
                   type="text"
                   data-bind="realTimeValue: newItemTitle" 
                   placeholder="New item name"
                   class="input-medium" />
            <button class="btn btn-info add-on" data-bind="click: addItem, disable: newItemTitle() === ''">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>
        </header>

        <article data-bind="if: selectedSection">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-bind="text: 'Items for ' + selectedSection().title()"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: selectedSection().items() -->
                    <tr id="item-list" data-bind="css: { 'selected': $root.isItemSelected($data) }">
                        <td data-bind="text: title" />
                    </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span>Count: <span data-bind="text: selectedSection().items().length"></span></span>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: There is just a lot of code to wade through and try to make sense of in the imagination. You seem to say it works some of the time. That does sound like a timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is just a lot of code to wade through and try to make sense of in the imagination.

You seem to say it works some of the time. That does sound like a timing issue.

One thing that is disturbing is the async methods (e.g. `setSelectedTemplate`) that return either false or a promise; not sure why the inconsistency. But that is probably not the real problem.

You could try putting a `setTimeout(..., 10)` before exiting the async methods. See if that changes the behavior.

If that doesn't reveal it, you'll have to boil it down to just those the essentials that reveal the problem.

Sadly no sudden flash of insight today.

### Update June 3

My first concern is that some of your methods return promises and some return the value `false`. I'd feel more comfortable if they all returned promises. Look at `Q.resolve()`.

Other code baffles me. For example, what is going on in the many variations on this pattern:

```
function setSelectedItem(data) {
            if (data) {
                selectedItem(data);
            } else {
                selectedItem();
            }
        }
```

The `else{...}` isn't doing anything useful. It unwraps the `selectedItem` property ... and discards the value. What is the point?

And what is the difference between this:

```
thisId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(selectedTemplate().id); // obscure
```

and this?

```
thisId = selectedTemplate().id(); // clear
```

Are you unsure whether `selectedTemplate().id` is a KO observable? The only reason to use `unwrapObservable` is when you are unsure.

As for timing, you can let KO know that it should re-fresh a binding by calling `valueHasMutated()` on an observable. For example:

```
function setFirstItemSelected() {
    setSelectedItem(selectedSection().items()[0]);
    selectedItem.valueHasMutated();
}
```

It might help. I don't know ... you're stacking a long chain of dependencies and it isn't easy to see which are bailing out when. That would take study of actual data flows as well as the code. You cannot reasonably expect your StackOverflow audience to work that hard for free.

Try cutting this way down to a super-simple example that displays the troublesome behavior.

Best of luck.

Comment: I ended up tackling the UI in a different way - so I am not facing this problem at the moment.  If it crops up again then I will address it then.

Comment: if you have time would you mind telling how I should be writing those async methods that you labelled "disturbing" e.g. setSelectedTemplate. I am going up a big learning curve with this whole approach at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue (same server, same client but sometimes some navigators not working in breeze) happened to me. In my opinion it can be a timing bug. Or the create/load order of entities count.

I've changed this paralell async load entities from server:

```
return promise = Q.all([                
            getPackage(),                
            getClubPartials(null, true),
            getAddressPartials(null, true),
            getEventPartials(null, true)
            ]).then(success);
```

to this get them one by one:

```
return getClubPartials(null, true).then(function () {
            getAddressPartials(null, true).then(function () {
                getEventPartials(null, true).then(function () {
                    return getPackage().then(success);
                })
            })
        });
```

And my problem gone!

Comment: I did have some timing issues similar to what you have described above.  However I do not think that is the problem with this specific problem.